# hibernate.xml not found error intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project which is connected to a mysql database.
When I run the main class it gives me the error:

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at repository.Repository.<init>(Repository.java:24)
at repository.FacultyRepository.<init>(FacultyRepository.java:20)
at main.main(main.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2005)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1986)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1966)
at repository.Repository.<init>(Repository.java:19)
... 7 more
```

I have read other answers and my configure.xml is in src/resources like follows:

[image]

Also, as you can see in printscreen, I have two errors in my file hibernate.
Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put hibernate.cfg.xml out of resources folder, at main level. Also, you must see your libraries are fine.
If not, must specify a different path

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
.configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: There are fine. I mean, I pressed there where it said fixed and it downloaded the libraries from internet and everything was good.

Comment: I resolved. I put the file at the main level. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Intellij Idea then make a folder named "resources" under src\main\java. Open Module setting of your project, select "Modules" from left and in the "sources" tab select the newly created "resources" folder and mark it as "Resources".[image]

then this should work

```
Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```